# How to get possibility of data sorting in datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, sorting, time

Short introduction:

- SQLite
- VB.NET
- NET.Framework 4.8
- Windows Forms
- Data Grid View

I have data value stored as String in SQLite in format DD.MM.YYYY ex. 01.01.2021 and I am trying display it in my data grid view. The values are displayed correctly, but I can't use sorting.
Beacues this is string so sorting is not working property - f.e.
sorting looks that:
01.01.2021
02.05.2021
03.02.2020

I am trying using `DataGridView1.Columns(31).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"` unfortunately it is also not working.
How can I convert string to date and display in column with possibility to sorting?

Thanks.

Comment: Convert it to a date

Comment: The driver can transform the TEXT Field Type to a DateTime (and the other way around), if you use the (standard, ISO) `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS` format. Assuming you're using System.Data.SQLite (or similar, ADO.Net, implementation).

Comment: *"How can I convert string to date"*. That is not a question for SO. If you don't know how to do that then you haven't actually tried because that would be easy to find out. If you haven't tried then it's too soon to be posting here.

Comment: I think you should change valuetype of column to `DataGridView1.Columns(31).valuetype = getType(date)` so you can sort it by date

Comment: Unfortunately, GetType(Date) doesn't help. Any ideas?